# How to tell app what to do after an item is selected from a dialog?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my app, there is a dialog that lets the user select an item. When the ok button is pressed the app should dial a number associated with the item. I'm able to get the items to show up in the dialog and the app knows that they're options, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the app process which was chosen and then dial the number.
Here's what I've got so far

```
 final CharSequence[] item = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};

         AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(crossingActivity.this);
   ab.setTitle("Which item?");
   ab.setSingleChoiceItems(item, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             }
         })
         .setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  if item = "item1"? android.intent.action.DIALtel:"number1";
              if item = "item2"? android.intent.action.DIALtel:"number2";
              if item = "item3"? android.intent.action.DIALtel:"number3";
              if item = "item4"? android.intent.action.DIALtel:"number4";
```

The dialog box opens and allows you to select an item, and that's where I'm stuck.
Eclipse gives me an error on all of the "if"s that says, "syntax error on token "if", invalid type. I think I'm just starting it wrong and I just don't know how to start it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statements don't make any sense.  You probably want to read up on basic java before attempting anything like this.  You could start with [if statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Multiple problems:  I think you are trying to compare item to a string value using =.  = is the assignment operator, == is used for comparison of primitives.  Using = is a syntax error.

However, since you are comparing strings you want to use .equals.

The `if blah ? thing1 : thing2` is a ternary operator, I don't think that is what you want here.  You just want to do something depending on the item selection.

```
if (item.equals("item1")) {
  dialNumber("number1");
} else if (item.equals("item2") {
  dialNumber("number2");
}
```

But as I said, please read through some basic java tutorials before trying to go further.

Comment: Technically == does work for strings because they are immutable and pooled, however it is not advisable to do so and poor style

Comment: @LINEMAN78 You are right it isn't a syntax error, and it will work sometimes, but you can't guarantee that it will work all the time, with any jre, so that just confuses the issue.

Comment: Agreed, I was just pointing out that the == operator only compares memory locations for Objects which for most JREs would work due to the string pool. But I do believe that your solution is the correct one and should be implemented.  Also, ternary operators in Java require that the result of the individual statements return something other than void and be assigned and cannot be purely used as a replacement for an if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be testing on the variable whichButton and match that to your item list?

As for using ? operator - I am not a fan of it, in addition to the reasons LINEMAN78 gave, I find that it's not as readable as the if-else logic....but it should work as you intended if your jre supports it.

Rule of thumb: always try to make your code readable...as your code base gets larger, the more effort it will take to maintain it.  Then eventually you haven't touched it for a long time - and you or someone else on your team have to learn your code all over again!